# Relating users based on activity selection

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I am working with Parse.com and would like to set up a condition where it would show the list of users who have also selected a particular activity page. For example, I have a list of items populated by JSON data, and where each item lead to a particular page. I would want to establish a condition that returns the users who have also selected that particular activity page to the current user.

If you need more information, let me know.
Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
This is what I have tried so far.
I am thinking of I would create a column called "activity name" in parse, and when a user clicks on that confirm button, the activity name would be recorded. Then in the matching activity, it would populate users where the activity name under the activity name column is equal.  For the matching code, I am thinking of

```
var activitycompare = new Parse.Query("Activity Name");
activitycompare.equalTo('Activity Name', string);
```

Something around that line. Any assistance or advice would be helpful.

**Update 2**
Thank you.
Please advise on the revised code, for I unexpectedly receive the following error:

```
userActivitySelectionName cannot be resolved to a variable
```

It would essentially see which users have selected that particular activity name and return it.

```
  public class MatchingActivity extends Activity {

 private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.matching);

        logoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);
        logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ParseUser.logOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        setConversationsList();
    }

    private void setConversationsList() {
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        names = new ArrayList<String>();


        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
       query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", currentUserId);
        query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++) {
                        names.add(userList.get(i).getUsername().toString());
                    }

                    usersListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.usersListView);
                    namesArrayAdapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.layout.user_list_item, names);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                            openConversation(names, i);
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error loading user list",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("username", names.get(pos));
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
           public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
               if (e == null) {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                   intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                   startActivity(intent);
               } else {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                       "Error finding that user",
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Give some information about the data structure and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I have added more information under the update section of my initial post. If you could assist me in anyway, I would be greatly thankful.

Comment: As per the error, you've used a variable called `userActivitySelectionName` that doesn't exist in the context... where are you reading this value from?

Comment: I randomly added this variable because I would like to retrieve the list of usersname who have selected that activity with the exception of the currentuser. I did not want to specificly point out a username since the list changes all the time, so was thinking of having a generic variable name such as userActivitySelectionName

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to record a single activity per user, then you would probably add it as a property to the `User` class. The correct query would then be (in Android):

```
var userQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
userQuery.whereEqualTo("activityName", someString);
userQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
  public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
        // The query was successful.
    } else {
        // Something went wrong.
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It has been greatly helpful so far. Since my activity is populated from JSON data, I was thinking of relating them based on the JSON string. I have included an update under my under 2 in my initial post.